# How to render EJS at anchor

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, mailchimp

I want to do something (maybe there's an easier way around that i'm not seeing) but basically what i'm trying to do is have an EJS file with a Mailchimp Sign Up form, and when the signup gets filled then it redirects to the same EJS File but this time with a variable that adds text to the HTML.

Basically when the user inputs the email we redirect him to the same section but this time it adds a p tag with the text "Thank you, we've got your email, we'll get in touch with you soon", here's my approach:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  mailchimp.post('/lists/' + process.env.MAILCHIMP_LIST + '/members', {
      email_address: req.body.email,
      status: 'subscribed'
    }, (err) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err.title);
      if(err.title == 'Member Exists'){
        res.redirect('/#signup', {
          Status: "Thank you, we've got your email, we'll get in touch with you soon"
        })
      }else{
        res.redirect('/#signup', {
          Status: "We're having problems signing you up, if the problem persists send an email to hello@hibuddie.com"
        })
      }
    }
  });
  res.redirect('/#signup', {
    Status: "Thank you, we've got your email, we'll get in touch with you soon"
  });
});
```

however when trying to do this I get an error on my console:

```
express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead app.js:45:7
```

I know that probably redirect wont work for EJS, but i don't know how to do it so it redirects the user to the same EJS file at a certain ID, say /#signup in this case.

Pardon my awful code, I'm getting started on this, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two way:

Instead of `redirect`ing you can use [`render`ing](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), and add the variable to the render function.

> ```
> // pass a local variable to the view
> res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function (err, html) {
>   // ...
> })
> ```

and Handle the variable in your view file.
You can Also send an `anchor` name as variable and add some javascript to handle it. like:

```
res.render('user', { anchor: 'signup' }, function (err, html) { ... });
```

And in the template file add some javascript,

```
window.onload = function (event) {
    window.location.hash = "#{{anchor}}";
};
```

**Or**, If you are using `Ajax` call to hit the api you can just return the status like,

```
res.json({
    success: true,//or false
    data: {
        Status: "some text"
    }
})
```

And handle it in the front end using Javascript.

Comment: If i use the rendering, how can i send the user to an specific section, say, i have a section with the id "signup", how can i render the 'index' file and once rendered "auto-scroll down" to the signup section?

Thank you :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include this.